# Hololens 2 Eye Tracking LayerMask

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

[image: my layers]

I want the eyetracking system to see all layers except "Built in Layer 7", how can I do it? I wrote a code like this but it doesn't work.

```
void Start()
{
    int layerMask = 1 << 8;
    layerMask = ~layerMask;
    Debug.Log(layerMask);  //-257
    CoreServices.InputSystem.EyeGazeProvider.GazePointer.PrioritizedLayerMasksOverride[0] = layerMask;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding from your previous thread, you want eye tracking raycast to ignore a specific layer. If it is the case, changing the priority won’t help and you need to navigate to [MixedRealityToolKit] -> [Input] -> [Pointer] -> [Pointing RayCast Layer Masks] and in the first Element, uncheck the layer that you don’t want to interact with eye gaze.
[image]

Comment: Thanks this solution worked for me but in this case, I cannot click on my object in the EyeTrackingIgnore layer. I want to click on the object but I don't want the eye-tracking pointer to see the object. My object contains an "Interactable" component.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGGWd.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOuM5.png

Comment: Do you mean simply do not display the dot when you look at an object? To be clear, it is simply a visual effect, which can be customized. You may check the official sample --https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/main/Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/EyeTracking, and in the root scene, when you look at a button, it simply shows a background, via activating an object.